# php xml xpath foreach to get values of nodes with same name

Tags: php, xml, xpath, foreach

Guys,

I have this xml code:

```
<items>
<item type="boardgame" id="84876">
<versions>
<item type="boardgameversion" id="317166">
<link type="boardgameversion" id="84876" value="The Castles of Burgundy" inbound="true"/>
<name type="primary" sortindex="1" value="Chinese Edition"/>
<link type="boardgamepublisher" id="9068" value="Broadway Toys LTD"/>
<link type="language" id="2181" value="Chinese"/>
</item>

<item type="boardgameversion" id="269360">
<link type="boardgameversion" id="84876" value="The Castles of Burgundy" inbound="true"/>
<name type="primary" sortindex="1" value="Hobby World Russian first edition"/>
<link type="boardgamepublisher" id="18852" value="Hobby World"/>
<link type="boardgameartist" id="11886" value="Julien Delval"/>
<link type="boardgameartist" id="4959" value="Harald Lieske"/>
<link type="language" id="2202" value="Russian"/>
</item>

<item type="boardgameversion" id="141049">
<link type="boardgameversion" id="84876" value="The Castles of Burgundy" inbound="true"/>
<name type="primary" sortindex="1" value="Ravensburger English/French Edition"/>
<link type="boardgamepublisher" id="9" value="alea"/>
<link type="boardgamepublisher" id="34" value="Ravensburger Spieleverlag GmbH"/>
<link type="boardgameartist" id="11886" value="Julien Delval"/>
<link type="boardgameartist" id="4959" value="Harald Lieske"/>
<link type="language" id="2184" value="English"/>
<link type="language" id="2187" value="French"/>
</item>

<item type="boardgameversion" id="69303">
<link type="boardgameversion" id="84876" value="The Castles of Burgundy" inbound="true"/>
<name type="primary" sortindex="1" value="Ravensburger Multilingual First Edition"/>
<link type="boardgamepublisher" id="9" value="alea"/>
<link type="boardgamepublisher" id="34" value="Ravensburger Spieleverlag GmbH"/>
<link type="boardgameartist" id="11886" value="Julien Delval"/>
<link type="boardgameartist" id="4959" value="Harald Lieske"/>
<link type="language" id="2184" value="English"/>
<link type="language" id="2187" value="French"/>
<link type="language" id="2188" value="German"/>
</item>

<item type="boardgameversion" id="134173">
<link type="boardgameversion" id="84876" value="The Castles of Burgundy" inbound="true"/>
<name type="primary" sortindex="1" value="Ravensburger Multilingual Second Edition"/>
<link type="boardgamepublisher" id="9" value="alea"/>
<link type="boardgamepublisher" id="34" value="Ravensburger Spieleverlag GmbH"/>
<link type="boardgameartist" id="11886" value="Julien Delval"/>
<link type="boardgameartist" id="4959" value="Harald Lieske"/>
<link type="language" id="2184" value="English"/>
<link type="language" id="2187" value="French"/>
<link type="language" id="2188" value="German"/>
</item>
</versions>
</item>
</items>
```

I want to get the values of  `<link type="language"...>`  for every version item.

My php code is:

```
$language = $xmlinfo2->item->versions->item;
$lang = $language->xpath('//link[@type="language"]');
$num = 1;

    foreach($language as $lang1) {
       echo $num . ". ";
         foreach ($lang as $lang2){
           $lang3 = $lang2->attributes();
           echo $lang3['value'] . ", ";
         }
         echo "<br>";
         $num++;
    }
```

Its results is (it writes all languages for all versions out):

1. Chinese, Russian, English, French, English, French, German, English, French, German,
2. Chinese, Russian, English, French, English, French, German, English, French, German,
3. Chinese, Russian, English, French, English, French, German, English, French, German,
4. Chinese, Russian, English, French, English, French, German, English, French, German,
5. Chinese, Russian, English, French, English, French, German, English, French, German,

**How do I have to change my php code to get this results?**

1. Chinese
2. Russian
3. English, French
4. English, French, German
5. English, French, German

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems here:

1) Using `//` at the start of an xpath selector means fetch these elements from **anywhere** in the document. So you end up with a list of all the languages from all the items each time you loop.

2) Your `xpath()` call needs to be inside the loop, or it won't work in the context of the current `<item>` that you're looking at.

So you can use something like:

```
foreach ($language as $lang1) {
    $lang = $lang1->xpath('link[@type="language"]');

    echo $num . ". ";

    foreach ($lang as $lang2){
        $lang3 = $lang2->attributes();
        echo $lang3['value'] . ", ";
    }

    echo "<br>";
    $num++;
}
```

Comment: It works really well.
Thank you for the code and for your description! Have a good day!